# How to remove shapefile from PostGIS

Tags: postgis, shapefile, postgresql

I added a shapefile to the PostGIS using,

```
ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL PG:"host=server_ip user=username dbname=dbname password=password" yourshapefile.shp;
```

Now I want to remove it. What is the command line code for that?

The table list is as follows `\d`,

```
List of relations
 Schema |         Name         |   Type   |  Owner  
--------+----------------------+----------+---------
 public | pimapine             | table    | smaranh
 public | pimapine_ogc_fid_seq | sequence | smaranh
(2 rows)
```

And when I execute `DROP TABLE public.pimapine` there is no change to the output of `\d`.

Comment: Did you include a semicolon at the end of your DROP TABLE command? Psql won't throw an error if you don't terminate your SQL statements with a semicolon. When the command has been accepted, it will print "DROP TABLE" on a line by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest way is with the [DropGeometryTable](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-2.0/DropGeometryTable.html) function. This will remove the table as well as entries in the geometry_columns table.

Comment: As it says in the documentation, DROP TABLE works just as well in v2.0

Comment: Right, PostGIS 2.0 does not have physical geometry_columns anymore, so standard drop is just fine.

Comment: Since he didn't specify version and DropGeometryTable is still in 2.0, I figured this was the cleaned way.

Answer (score 2):

1. open your db with pgadmin
2. find the shapefile-table in the public schema
3. drop it

or if you want to use psaq:

```
psql -c "drop table public.shapefile;"
```

Comment: just updated the question